# Question on the equivalence of behaviour strategy and mixed strategy for a player with a single information set

Tags: game-theory, decision-theory

> Prove that if a player in an extensive-form game has only one [information set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_set_(game_theory)), then his set of mixed strategies equals his set of behavior strategies.

This is the exercise $6.4$ on page $246$ in [Game Theory by Michael Maschler, Eilon Solan and Shmuel Zamir](http://books.google.com.hk/books?hl=zh-CN&id=lqwzqgvhwXsC&q=246#v=snippet&q=246&f=false).

But I think the example game $A$(absent-minded driver game) in $6.3$ invalidate this claim, since Player I can't reach the payoff $10$ by a mixed strategy but it's not the case for a behavior stategy. What's wrong?

[image]

**Added**：
[image]

Comment: I think your counterexample is spot on. You might want to contact Eilon Solan, who manages a [list of typos](https://sites.google.com/site/eilonsolanphd/publications#TOC-Books).

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Not so fast. :) It is conceivable that "extensive-form game" has actually been _defined_ (in the book) as "finite extensive-form game with perfect recall".

Comment: @aufkag No. Exercise 6.3, the one that comes before, deals explicitely with cases of imperfect recall. Also, the chapter is *Behavior strategies and Kuhn's Theorem*.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker OK. But (for my information): What then is their _formal_ definition of a behaviour strategy? Wikipedia speaks of assignment at _nodes_, whereas you seem to think of assignment at _information sets_. (Which does make more sense.)

Comment: @aufkag I don't have a copy of the book. Sadly.

Comment: @aufkag,  I add a screenshot of definition of behavior strategy from googlebooks.

Comment: @MettaWorldPeace Yes, great. Now, the question is: for the purpose of that definition, _how many_ possible actions at the information set in Game A are there? 2, 4, or 3? :) What do you think?

Comment: @aufkag, I think it's 4, but I haven't found a definition of it in the book.

Comment: @MettaWorldPeace Will you let us (well: me) know what Solan has to say?

Comment: @aufkag, No problem, but I think I had better wait for a day or so to make sure I haven't missed something. If nothing new is found, I'll send Solan an Email, and post his reply here.

Comment: @Transmissionfrom, Hi, maybe you have noticed that Solan gave his correction on our website. This exercise is in fact a step in a theorem, but I haven't thought of it throughly. I think I will have time tomorrow to add some relevant information to make this question more "complete".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EilonSolan Many thanks for drawing our attention to the way this exercise was phrased. We should have been more careful. Here is the new version of the exercise. I hope now it is clear. [image: The new Exercise 6.4]